How to automate Scroll bar with Range in Selenium?
I am trying to automate a scroll bar with a range of 0 to 5 and a step of 0.5 on the below page.
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/horizontal_slider
Below is the code.
driver.get(baseURI + "/horizontal_slider");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
        
String value = element.getAttribute("value");       
System.out.println("Slider Value is " + value);         

Actions action = new Actions(driver);       

action.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).release().build().perform();

    action.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).release().build().perform();

value = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("Slider Value is " + value); 

First time when I used sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT) once. I see that the scroll bar is moving by 3 points. after that, it moves by 0.5 points every time.
I tried using JavascriptExecutor as well with the below code.
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollBy(1, 0);", element);

And also tried using the scrollByAmount method as well with the below code.
action.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().scrollByAmount(1, 0).release().build().perform();

However, It moves by 2.5 points at the beginning and then later by 0.5.

First, set the slider to a certain value, e.g. 0
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments.value = arguments;", element, "0");

Then you use the Actions class to move the slider to the right in small steps (10 steps):
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    action.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).release().perform();
    Thread.sleep(500);
}

After each adjustment, you can verify the slider’s value to ensure it is moving as expected.
String value = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("Slider Value is " + value);

